# Por que não consigo exibir o valor no print?

Tags: swift-3

Quero exibir no console o valor da variável nome o que aparece é "(lldb)", por que isso?

```
@IBAction func botaoAcesse(_ sender: Any) {

    let cpf = self.campoCPF.text
    let senha = self.campoSenha.text

    let param = ["cpf": cpf, "senha": senha, "method": "app-get-login", "plataforma":"ios"]
    var _: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
    let url = "http://easypasse.com.br/gestao/wsLogin.php"

    Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, parameters:param,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print(response)
            if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                let registro =  JSON["registro"] as? String
                let usuario = JSON["usuario"] as? String
                let nome = JSON["nome"] as? String
                print(nome!)

            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(0,"Error")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Caro amigo,

Primeiro comece ajustando o seu Json de retorno, pois não me parece que está correto e por isso ele pode não estar entrando no seu if let.

Para te auxiliar sugiro validar seu json no site : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Mas isso é um objeto json, dentro de outro.

Comment: E foi outra pessoa quem fez.

Comment: o JSON está correto! Veja
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270389/why-cant-i-show-data-in-print
E eu testei o código e deu certo.